# Else without If (help needed)

Tags: java, if-statement, brackets

I must be missing something here but i cannot see where the error is in this piece of code keeps saying 
Test.java:63: error: illegal start of expression

```
                            }else 
                            ^
```

Test.java:63: error: 'else' without 'if'

```
                           }else



public static int[] awardcal(int awardsum, int[] award, double[] gpa, boolean[] need, int count, double classadvarge){
                for(int index = 0; index < count; index ++){   
                      if (gpa[index] == 4.00){
                            awardsum += 1000;
                                if(need[index] == true){
                            awardsum += 500;
                                }else awardsum += 200;    
                      }else 
                      if (gpa[index] <= 3.70 && gpa[index] < 4.00){
                            if (need[index] == true){
                                   awardsum += 500;
                                if (gpa[index] >= classaverage){
                                   awardsum += 500;
                                }else     
                           }else
                      }else                              
                      if (gpa[index] >= classaverage){
                         awardsum += 200;
                      }else

                      if (gpa[index] >= classaverage){
                            if (need[index] == true){
                                awardsum += 500;
                            }else 
                                awardsum += 200;
                      }else 
                 award[index] = awardsum;
                 return award;                                         
                }
        }
```

Comment: Often the problem is poor code indentation preventing you from seeing if ifs and elses are matched. Fix this with care. But yeah, your code doesn't make sense as you've got a dangling `else` at the top.

Comment: Your `else`s don't make sense.

Comment: In fact that first else appears to be dangling out in space, outside of any and all methods and constructors. Please strive to post your actual code with your questions unless your goal is just to confuse and confound us.

Comment: You miss placed the return statement. It returns the award in first iteration. Place it after the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Open bracket after else?

```
if(){

} else {

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your understanding of `if/else` construct. You may or may not need an `else` scenario, so no need to use `else` in that case. As you have put multiple such `else` in your code, which seems to be of no use. It seems you just use it as if it is mandated to use `else` with `if`. Also always use curly braces to start and end if or else block to avoid errors.

Following marked else seems unnecessary:

```
     if (gpa[index] >= classaverage){
         awardsum += 500;
      }else     // seems not required
 }else // seems not required
```

Answer (score 0):

How to use [if-else statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

```
   if (gpa[index] >= classaverage)
        {
             awardsum += 500;
        }
         else //unwanted else    
     }else //unwanted else
    }else                              
    if (gpa[index] >= classaverage){
```

You also made the mistake while returning the `return award;`. You placed with in the loop. Place it after the loop ends

This the formatted code try it

```
public static int[] awardcal(int awardsum, int[] award, double[] gpa, boolean[] need, int count, double classadvarge)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
            if (gpa[index] == 4.00)
            {
                awardsum += 1000;
                if (need[index] == true)
                {
                    awardsum += 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    awardsum += 200;
                }
            }
            else if (gpa[index] <= 3.70 & gpa[index] < 4.00)
            {
                if (need[index] == true)
                {
                    awardsum += 500;
                    if (gpa[index] >= classaverage)
                    {
                        awardsum += 500;
                    }
                    else //unused else
                    {

                    }
                }
                else //unused else
                {

                }
            }
            else if (gpa[index] >= classaverage)
            {
                awardsum += 200;
            }
            else if (gpa[index] >= classaverage)
            {
                if (need[index] == true)
                {
                    awardsum += 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    awardsum += 200;
                }
            }
            else
            {


        award[index] = awardsum;
                }
//            return award; // you wrongly placed the return statement
            }
            return award;  // This will return the whole array
        }
```